# Even distribution of weighted sums across a period of time

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, machine-learning

I want to automatically&optimally split and distribute a number in several buckets as evenly as possible across a period of time.

*Example*:

- **5000** across **12 months**, in **6 buckets**, with weights **15%, 20%, 15%, 10%, 30%, 10%**, and a minimum of **100** per month per bucket; that is **~416** per month across buckets

*Rules:*

- This is the catch: there has to be a minimum in each bucket (100 in our example; obviously, if this is zero, then the solution is very easy aka just an average)
- Amount in each bucket doesn't have to be a whole number
- Weights must be respected
- Each bucket may skip a month of two, just so the sum per month across buckets adds up to 416

*An example of my manual effort*
[image]

*Generalization and nice-to-haves*

- Configurable number of buckets & number of periods
- Configurable minimum amount per bucket per month

*References*

- [Distribute value evenly across a number of cells](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/7qow17/distribute_value_evenly_across_a_number_of_cells/dsqx1dt?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  It's not clear how the weights should affect the solution.  I don't know what "weights must be respected" means.  I don't know what you mean by months and buckets.  An example spreadsheet is not a substitute for a general specification of the task.  What are the inputs, and what is the desired output?  Also we require you to articulate a specific question.